# How can I recover PNG images from a .pvr.ccz file?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures, texturepacker

I have an existing Cocos2D game that uses sprite images taken from a .pvr.ccz file, probably generated by TexturePacker. However, I don't have the original PNG images used to create that file, and I need to make some changes to the images in the game. Are there any tools or techniques that I can use to pull the images out of the .pvr.ccz file, or do I need to write my own tool?

Comment: I think if you download the TexturePacker , you can open the file (I just tried a .pvr.gz) and it offers a 'File->Save As' menu ... after you go through the ritual of clicking on 'Free Version' :)

Comment: errr ... you might have to 'un ccz' by hand, some sloc's involved. sneaky !

Comment: @YvesLeBorg TexturePacker can display the file in the "PVR viewer", but I don't see a way to pull out all the component images into separate files.

Comment: ah ... well the components dont exist as components in the pvr file, i had misunderstood your intent. They exist in the 'source' Texture Packer package from which the .pvr was concocted. You can at best(probably) get the compound .png with all components onto a single texture.

Comment: Is there no accompanying .plist file? That would make extraction a lot easier.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D There is, I have the .plist, and I can use that. Was just hoping that either TexturePacker or some other tool already knew how to extract the images.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Right, you can get a single image file with all the components. There's also a property list that gives you the info for each component -- mostly the name and the frame in the compound PNG. So it wouldn't be rocket science to write a program that reads the property list, copies each image out of the compound PNG, and saves it to a new PNG file with its original name. I could do that, but it seems like such an obvious operation that there'd be a way to have TexturePacker (or some other tool) use the .plist to reverse the operation.

Comment: yep ... i do software, and usually leave product questions to the marketroids of the world ... should be part of TexturePacker really (did not check if it is). But all in all, maybe 20-30 lines of objc or so with cocos2d :).

Answer (score 1):

Not possible if they use the encryption option of Texture Packer:

> I've added a new feature to TexturePacker which helps you to prevent all this from happening. It's called ContentProtection and simply encrypts the images.
>
> Your app will still be able to decrypt the data, but somebody else is going to have a hard time getting it done.

Source:  https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/contentprotection