# Convert PVR.CCZ image to PNG for edit the image.

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I  need to convert PVR.CCZ image file to PNG image to edit my image file.  m original image got deleted. i used texture packer to create pvr file.

i refer this link:- [How can I recover PNG images from a .pvr.ccz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453913/how-can-i-recover-png-images-from-a-pvr-ccz-file)  but not useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Googling u will get. i got this link:- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69519/how-can-i-batch-convert-texturepacker-pvr-ccz-files-to-png  its worked fine also..

Simple command in terminal will help:-

```
TexturePacker filename.pvr.ccz --sheet filename.png --data dummy.plist --algorithm Basic --allow-free-size --no-trim
```